# Optional @PathParam in Jax-RS

Tags: java, regex, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I have a service where the last part of the path is optional, the user can both enter **/mypath/** and **/mypath/param1/**.

I tried to use a regular expression to filter the last part of the path:

`@Path("/mypath{param1: (/param1)?}")`

I'm using RestEasy as my JAX-RS provider and the code works as expected in Tomcat but when I deploy it in JBoss I get a 405 return code when I do not submit the optional part.

Am I doing something wrong here or it's not possible to accomplish this in a portable way?

Comment: [**See Also**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32765804/2587435)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The problem was the lack of whitespace before the colon:

```java
@Path("/mypath{param1: (/param1)?}")
```

should be:

```java
@Path("/mypath{param1 : (/param1)?}")
```

Apparently it's a bug, because the [specification](http://jackson.codehaus.org/javadoc/jax-rs/1.0/index.html?javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html) makes the whitespace around the colon optional. I also found that I'm not the first [bitten by this bug](http://corneliadavis.com/blog/2010/10/20/jax-rs-regular-expressions-in-path-annotations/).

Comment: Not working in my case but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32778643/3143670) does

Comment: @NeerajJain my question involves RestEasy, the one you linked is about Jersey.

Comment: The value of `param1` includes the slash (`/`). Without manually cutting the slash in the code, is there a way to not include the slash in the value?

Answer (score 11):

In my case I had to use this other expression:

`@Path('/mypath/{param1 : (\\w+)?}')`

Otherwise you have to clean the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Verify whether there is a path already defined with /mypath that accepts a different method, this could be the reason why you are getting 405 (Method not allowed) back. Also when you have optional parameters I guess it is better to make them query parameters.

Comment: This was the error that I was getting. I had a `GET` at / and a `POST` at /{filename} where filename was optional. So the post at GET and POST were clashing.

Answer (score -12):

With Dropwizard 1.0 and Java8 you can use Optional

```
@Path("/news")
getLastNews(@QueryParam("topicId") String topicId, @QueryParam("limit") Optional<Integer> limit)
```

It will give a response to both

```
/news?topicId=123213?limit=200
```

and

```
/news?topicId=123213
```

Comment: It is about `@Path` not `@QueryParam`