# Optional param not working in jersey using regex

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I am working to cater REST url of three types:

1. `url/detail/3`    (integer only)
2. `url/detail/hello`    (String only)
3. `url/detail/3/1d`

For URL 1 and 3 I am using `method1` and for URL 2 `method2` is used.

**Problem 1:** All requests type of 1 and 2 matches method 2 only.Though I've specified Integer pattern in method 1 for queries having integer specifically.

**Problem 2:** To use an optional param (like in 3) I am using method1 because jersey doesn't provide any option for optional param.But url types of `url/detail/3/1d`   is never matched as specified in method 1.

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong as I am newbie to jersey.

```
@GET
@Path("/detail/{id: \\d+}/{time-period:(/time-period/[^/]+?)?}")

@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JResponse method1(
        @Context HttpHeaders headers,
        @PathParam("id") String id,
        @PathParam("time-period") String timePeriod) {
    if(timePeriod == null || timePeriod.equals(""))
    {
        //code
    }
    else
      //code
}
@GET
@Path("/detail/{name}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JResponse method2(
        @Context HttpHeaders headers, @PathParam("name") String name) {
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a missing whitespace leads to the problem. See [Optional @PathParam in Jax-RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421104/optional-pathparam-in-jax-rs)

You can define default values for parameters with `@DefaultValue("1000")`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of complicated regexps you should probably use [subresource](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e1704).

Answer (score 0):

@Path("detail/{id}{time-perioid:(/[^/]+?)?}")

http://x.y.z:4080/analytics/internal/detail/kala

2014-01-17 07:35:50,509 [http-nio-4080-exec-8] INFO  xxx - id: kala

2014-01-17 07:35:50,510 [http-nio-4080-exec-8] INFO  xxx - time-period:

and

http://x.y.z:4080/analytics/internal/detail/kala/123

2014-01-17 07:36:01,644 [http-nio-4080-exec-9] INFO  xxx - id: kala

2014-01-17 07:36:01,645 [http-nio-4080-exec-9] INFO  xxx - time-period: /123

If id can be string or integer I would go validating it inside handler.