# Option path parameters returning 404 in Jersey

Tags: jersey

I'm trying to use a path like this, with the last parameter optional, so that if it's present it's used, otherwise it's simply set to null or empty.

```
@Path("/create/{param1}{param2:(/param2/[^/]+?)?}")
```

However I get a 200 when the first static parameter is set, but i get a 404 (not found) when the second option parameter is set as well.

For example, this fails with a 404:

```
http://hostname/create/abc1/abc2
```

and this succeeds with a 200:

```
http://hostname/create/abc1
```

What am I doing wrong with that optional path that Jersey can't match it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I'm sure there are solutions to this issue, I resolved it by overloading the method so that a single param is sent to one receiving method and both params are sent to another. They then both hand off to a handler method so we reduce code duplication.
This works using simple java overloading and removes the need to complicated matching syntax, which will make later maintenance easier.

```
@PUT
@Path("/create/{param1}")
public Response doThingMethod(@PathParam("param1") String param1){
    return passToHandler(param1, null)
}

@PUT
@Path("/create/{param1}/{param2}")
public Response doThingMethod(@PathParam("param1") String param1, @PathParam("param2") String param2){
    return passToHandler(param1, param2)
}
```

Hopefully, that helps someone else having the same issue.

Comment: Marked this one as a solution since nobody seems to have an answer and  this method seems to work just fine with less complexity.

Comment: Same here... btw while doing research for this issue I stumbled upon this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5471878/1427210 which states colon between that name of the param and regexp should be separated by white space. Although I have met this requirement it didn't work either.