# Optional params in REST API request using Jersey 2.21

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

I'm playing around with `Jersey 2.21` and I'd like to know if it's possible to have an "optional" param which can, or not, be present in the request made to the server.

I want to successfully access this two methods:

```
http://localhost:8080/my_domain/rest/api/myMethod/1
http://localhost:8080/my_domain/rest/api/myMethod
```

As you can see, I'm trying to make the integer (`id`) param an optional one.

I've declared `myMethod` as follows:

```
@GET
@Path("myMethod/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8")
public String myMethod(@PathParam("id") Integer id, @Context HttpHeaders hh)
```

This works:

```
http://localhost:8080/my_domain/rest/api/myMethod/1
```

and this works too:

```
http://localhost:8080/my_domain/rest/api/myMethod/
```

but **this won't work** and I don't understand why. It throws a `404 Not Found` error:

```
http://localhost:8080/my_domain/rest/api/myMethod
```

Can you point me in the right direction to work this out? I don't like the slash being mandatory on all my REST method calls and would like to suppress it if possible.

Comment: @peeskillet please read carefully the question, as this is not a duplicate. The other question regards using the slash at the end of the request but in my question I ask for getting rid of it.

Comment: Sorry. I don't think you can get rid of it. I've explored the possibility a few times and couldn't find an answer. Maybe there is one who knows. I would just make two methods. Doesn't really make sense to me two have just one method. One method for the collection, and one for the single resource.

Comment: And actually it does answer your question as it is making the slash optional using a regex. Did you even try?. I guess I jumped to quick again. The problem I was trying to figure out was bit different

Comment: @peeskillet Yes, indeed I tried the regex but with no luck, the slash was still mandatory. Did it work for you? Maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: I have never used it in real code (for the reason mentioned above), but answering questions, I've tested it many times, and it should work.  Did you use something like `myMethod{id: (/\\d+)?}`? The `?` behind the parenthesis says that everything include in the parenthesis is optional. So `/` followed by digits is allowed but not required.

Comment: `@Path("/myMethod{id : (/id)?}")` throws 404 when I try to access `http://localhost:8080/my_domain/rest/api/myMethod/1` but it lets me access `http://localhost:8080/my_domain/rest/api/myMethod` and `http://localhost:8080/my_domain/rest/api/myMethod/` . This is how it is pictured on the `application.wadl` :
`<resource path="/mypath{id : (/id)?}"><param name="id" style="template" type="xs:int"/><method id="myMethod" name="GET"><response><representation mediaType="application/json;charset=UTF-8"/></response></method></resource></resource>`

Comment: Do you know what `(/id)?` means in regex? You are saying that only `/id` is allowed. So you can only access `/mymthod/id`. You need to actually use a regex that will match what you want. See my previous comment. `\\d+` means any number of digits

Comment: @peeskillet yes, I did try with your regex suggestion but didn't work when I passed a param in the request `(http://localhost:8080/my_domain/rest/api/myMethod/1)` but worked when there was no param and/or no slash `(http://localhost:8080/my_domain/rest/api/myMethod)`, `(http://localhost:8080/my_domain/rest/api/myMethod/)`

Comment: I see the problem. It won't work with integer parameters. Here's what happens. When we use `(/\\d+)`, the `/` is part of the `{id}` param. So when we use `@PathParam("id") int id`, it tries to parse `/1` to an int. When an exception is thrown during parsing, it leads to a 404. Only options going this way is to use String param, and remove the leading `/` and parse it yourself. A headache compared to simply having two resource methods. That is definitely the way I recommend :-)

Comment: Hm, that could be... can you check if this regex is correct for my purpouse? I can't access the method although I changed the param to `String`:   
`@GET
 @Path("myMethod{id : (/\\d+)?}")
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8")
 public String myMethod(@PathParam("id") String id, @Context HttpHeaders hh)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90591/discussion-between-peeskillet-and-jorgegrc).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So after some dabbling around with some of the answers in [Optional @PathParam in Jax-RS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5421104/2587435), the problem is that using this

```
@Path("/myMethod{id: (/\\d+)?}") 
public Response get(@PathParam("id") int id) {}
```

causes the `/` to be in the capture group. So when Jersey tries to parse `/1` it will get an exception and send a 404. We could use a String, but then it gets ugly, as we need to get rid of the leading `/` *and* parse it ourselves.

```
@Path("/myMethod{id: (/\\d+)?}") 
public Response get(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    id = id.replace("/", "");
    int parsed = Integer.parseInt(id);
}
```

The other solution I came up with (the one that works for the OP), is to separate the `/` from the digits into two different path expressions, so that the leading `/` is not captured in the actual id and doesn't fail in parsing

```
@Path("/method{noop: (/)?}{id: ((?<=/)\\d+)?}")
public Response get(@PathParam("id") int id) {}
```

The `{noop: (/)?}` captures the optional `/`. And the `{id: ((?<=/)\\d+)?}` uses a [positive lookbehind](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/regex/simple-positive-lookbehind/), saying that the numbers (`\\d+`) are allowed if and only if there is a `/` before it (`(?<=/)`). This is necessary as the `/` is optional. If we didn't use this assertion, then `/myMethod123` would be allowed.

Here is a complete test case using [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html)

```
public class OptionalParamTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Path("optional")
    public static class Resource {
        @GET
        @Path("/method{noop: (/)?}{id: ((?<=/)\\d+)?}")
        public String get(@PathParam("id") int id) {
            return String.valueOf(id);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(Resource.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void should_return_id_1() {
        Response response = target("optional/method/1").request().get();
        System.out.println("status=" + response.getStatus());
        assertEquals("1", response.readEntity(String.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void should_return_id_0_with_no_id() {
        Response response = target("optional/method").request().get();
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        assertEquals("0", response.readEntity(String.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void should_return_404_with_numbers_and_no_slash() {
        Response response = target("optional/method12").request().get();
        assertEquals(404, response.getStatus());
    } 

    @Test
    public void should_return_404_with_numbers_and_letters() {
        Response response = target("optional/method/12b").request().get();
        assertEquals(404, response.getStatus());
    }

    @Test
    public void should_return_404_with_only_letters() {
        Response response = target("optional/method/ab").request().get();
        assertEquals(404, response.getStatus());
    } 
}
```

Here's the dependency for the test

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

#### EDIT

For the tests, it would be better to use a boxed `Integer` instead of an `int` as the method parameter. With the former you would be able to do a null check, instead of receiving the default `0` for the primitive.

Comment: Great and elaborated answer. Thanks a lot for your time :)

Comment: I'm facing now a problem related to this solution and the regex expression... When making a `POST` request with form params to the same path used in the `GET` (two different web services, one is triggered by a `POST` request and the other by a `GET` request, but they share the same path: `/routes`) it throws a `405 Method not Allowed`. While debugging on my browser I found that this `405` response comes with the param `Allow: GET, OPTIONS`. Have you got any idea of what can be causing this behaviour? If I remove the regex expression from the `GET`, it correctly runs the `POST` service.

Comment: You should probably post another question with complete details

Answer (score 14):

There is a *way* easier way to do this:

```
@GET
@Path("myMethod/{id}")
public String myMethod(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
}

@GET
@Path("myMethod")
public String myMethod() {
  return myMethod(null);
}
```

No tricky regex required.

Comment: Great and simple solution!