# How to have an optional slash in a jax-rs endpoint in the case of optional query params

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have a path with three query params like this:

```
@Path("/insert/{op}/{id}/{status:.*}")
```

The last param, status, is optional.

So right now I can hit it with either: `/insert/a/b/c`

or: `/insert/a/b/`

Is there a way I can make the final '/' optional as well though, so that I can do this: `/insert/a/b`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32778643/2587435)

Comment: Trailing slashes are always optional.

Comment: Have you tried `/insert/a/b`? What happens when you do?

Comment: Yes I've tried it. I get a 404 Not Found

Comment: @peeskillet Thank you very much. I don't know why I couldn't find that Question in my search. That was exactly what I needed. Thanks.