# Does not regex in Jersey @Path support `Lookahead`?

Tags: java, regex, jakarta-ee, jersey

`@Path("/{firstName: ^(?!nameblacklist$).*$}/{lastName: .*}")`

I just want to make this resource not to match string like `/nameblacklist/start`. But it failed me when testing.

Does not Does not regex in Jersey @Path support complicated expression?

Comment: If it worked as is expected, `/nameblacklist/start` will return 404, and other string will be matched

Comment: Here is an example of a lookbehind working https://stackoverflow.com/a/32778643/2587435. I don't see why a lookahead would not work.